# Display (Title-Start Time-End Time) in SharePoint 2010 Calendar Month View

Tags: sharepoint-designer

Currently in SharePoint 2010 month view calendar, Start Time is shown by default followed by Title. Can any one please let me how to display (Title-Start Time-End Time) in a month view and I don't want Start Time in the beginning.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Create a calculated column called MonthDisplay and have it concatenate those fields together. Then in the list view settings for the view, tell it to use the MonthDisplay field as the title.

Comment: Yes, I did, But still it shows start time in the front followed by (Title-StartEndTime)

Comment: Sorry it works fine. but can we control the text in the mouse hover. I want to hide part of the text on mouse hover